# adding line between rows of table in PDF

Tags: itext

my code is like that, here `it` is `ITextSharp.Text`.

I'd like to ask, if I want to add black lines between each row, how to do it?
I tried to find the property of `ITEXTSharp.Text.Table`, but I cannot find there is any property there.

```
it.Document doc = new it.Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create));        
doc.Open();
it.Phrase p = new it.Phrase("item1", new it.Font(testBaseFont, 14, it.Font.BOLD, it.Color.BLACK));
p = new it.Phrase("item2", new it.Font(testBaseFont, 14, it.Font.BOLD, it.Color.BLACK));
p.Leading = 2;
doc.Add(p);
it.Table logTable = new it.Table(5);
logTable.Alignment = it.Table.ALIGN_LEFT;
logTable.DefaultVerticalAlignment = it.Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
logTable.Width = 100;
logTable.Border = it.Table.TOP_BORDER | it.Table.BOTTOM_BORDER;
logTable.BorderWidth = 0.5f;
logTable.DefaultCellBorder = 0;
logTable.Cellspacing = 2;
logTable.Cellpadding = 0;
logTable.DefaultCellBackgroundColor = it.Color.WHITE;
logTable.SetWidths(new int[] { 20, 20, 20, 20, 20 });
//Write column headers
logTable.AddCell(new it.Phrase("Column1", tableHeaderFont));
logTable.AddCell(new it.Phrase("Column2", tableHeaderFont));
logTable.AddCell(new it.Phrase("Column3", tableHeaderFont));
logTable.AddCell(new it.Phrase("Column4", tableHeaderFont));
logTable.AddCell(new it.Phrase("Column5", tableHeaderFont));

logTable.AddCell(new it.Cell(new it.Phrase("1", tableCellFont)));
logTable.AddCell(new it.Phrase("12", tableCellFont));
logTable.AddCell(new it.Phrase("13", tableCellFont));
logTable.AddCell(new it.Phrase("14", tableCellFont));
logTable.AddCell(new it.Phrase("15", tableCellFont));


logTable.AddCell(new it.Cell(new it.Phrase("2", tableCellFont)));
logTable.AddCell(new it.Phrase("22", tableCellFont));
logTable.AddCell(new it.Phrase("23", tableCellFont));
logTable.AddCell(new it.Phrase("24", tableCellFont));
logTable.AddCell(new it.Phrase("25", tableCellFont));

doc.Add(logTable);
doc.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `Table` was [deprecated many](http://itextsharp.10939.n7.nabble.com/PdfPTable-vs-Table-td3848.html) [years ago](http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Difference-between-Table-and-PdfPTable-td2156560.html) in favor of `PdfPTable` so you'll want to switch to that.

Then it is just a matter of changing the `DefaultCell` of your table instance.

```
var t = new PdfPTable(2);
//Use only a bottom border
t.DefaultCell.Border = PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    t.AddCell("Hello");
    t.AddCell(i.ToString());
}
```

If you still want the full table border but just extra-thick bottom borders for rows you can do that, too:

```
var t = new PdfPTable(2);
//Use a thicker border for the bottom
t.DefaultCell.BorderWidthBottom = 2;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    t.AddCell("Hello");
    t.AddCell(i.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris Haas,thank you very much for your kindness help. Well now I'd better not switch to PdfPTable since I should wait for the reply from my colleagues who are in vacation. But anyway it is same to add DefaultCell.Border in my case.